# Getting the index of multiple selected items in a listbox using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox which is made up of Grid Items in Multiple SelectionMode in Silverlight 3.0.

When I use ListBox.SelectedIndex it only returns the first item which is selected.

I would like to be able see all of the selected items such that it would return all of the selected item indexes' such as; 2, 5, and 7, etc.

Any help?

Cheers,

Turtlepower.

Comment: Did you check whether there is a property named SelectedIndices/SelectedIndexList or similar ?

Comment: ListBox in Silverlight doesn't have SelectedIndices , but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the selected indexes by iterating through `SelectedItems` and finding the objects in the `Items` property, like this:

```
List<int> selectedItemIndexes = new List<int>();
foreach (object o in listBox.SelectedItems)
    selectedItemIndexes.Add(listBox.Items.IndexOf(o));
```

Or if you prefer linq:

```
List<int> selectedItemIndexes = (from object o in listBox.SelectedItems select listBox.Items.IndexOf(o)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh, it's nearly working.

Strangely I have only 5 Items in my listbox and when I return them all I get 7 items which goes "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0". Why the extra three 0's on the end?

Comment: 5 items as in selected items? Can you post the code you are using to "return them"?

Comment: List<int> selectedItemIndexes = new List<int>();
            foreach (object o in myListBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                selectedItemIndexes.Add(myListBox.Items.IndexOf(o));
            }

Yes, 5 items and I only select 5 items too. Odd.

Comment: Ahh, as in when I am in the debugger and open up the List collection I see a trailing end of 0's after the selected items.

Comment: Update: doesn't seem to do it when I actually return the selectedItemsIndexes[i], must just be a trail off thing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if items are simple strings - "IndexOf" will return FIRST match if you have duplicate strings.