# Get all selected items in ListBox (including duplicates)

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, duplicates, selecteditem

I have a ListBox that contains duplicate items. From what I gather, `ListBox.SelectedItems` will only return the first instance of a duplicate, but this causes problems when I want to perform an action on all items a user has selected. When I select multiple duplicates and call `ListBox.SelectedItems.Count`, I always get `1`. Is there a way to get the indexes of all items, regardless if they're unique or not? (ListBox mode is set to Multiple).

Added repro code demonstrating that the same item is considered a duplicate.

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
   <ListBox Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
   <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="313,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

code:

```
ObservableCollection<string> fruits = new ObservableCollection<string>();
fruits.Add("Apple");
fruits.Add("Pear");
fruits.Add("Orange");
fruits.Add("Apple");
listBox1.ItemsSource = fruits ;
```

I just wired up a button event to this:

```
MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItems.Count.ToString());
```

Select the top `Apple` and click the button, it will return `1`. Select both `Apples` and it will return `1`. Select an `Apple` and `Pear`, it will return `2`.

Comment: ListBox.GetSelectedIndices() possibly?

Comment: Thanks, but that method doesn't exist in Silverlight. My post was edited to include the 'asp.net' tag, but this is not asp.net.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about silverlight. I was looking at the C# tag. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836313/getting-the-index-of-multiple-selected-items-in-a-listbox-using-silverlight

Comment: No, unfortunately that foreach loop only goes round once because it considers any duplicates as just one item rather than separate ones.

Comment: That is really weird that the ListBox cares in the element are the same. WHere did you SelectedItems returns only the first distinct element?

Comment: @MBen - I read that it's by design in this thread (the accepted answer) http://forums.asp.net/t/1070953.aspx/1 I assume I'm running into that issue.

Comment: Are you doing asp.Net or silverlight?

Comment: Silverlight, but the issue seems to be the same (I might be wrong)

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue, created a multi select list box with items 
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
but i get correct selectItems and the count value.

Comment: Maybe it might be the way I'm binding it. ObservableCollection and using ListBox.ItemSource = obCol;

Comment: Can you provide sample code/xaml for context? It would be very unusual from a GUI standpoint to have two instances of the same object in a ListBox.

Comment: @HiTechMagic - I've added repro code.

Comment: Rather that using an `ObservableCollection<string>` you could try with an `ObservableCollection<Fruit>`.

Comment: The problem I had was if I inserted the code above, and then clicked the first Apple, it highlighted both.. so it clearly does see both as identical.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti - Same thing happens whether it's a class or a simple string.

Comment: Again I say, it is *very* unusual to have duplicates in any sort of user selection... Why do you have duplicates? I realise your code is an example, but how is the user supposed to know which "Apples" they are choosing if they look the same? :)

Comment: @HiTechMagic - Sorry, I see what you mean. What happens is that the user sees another listbox and selects items from there. So there's a listbox with unique values and the user selects the fruits from there. The selected ListBoxItem is cast to a fruit and added to the ObservableCollection. The particular apple doesn't matter, just the fact that they chose an apple.

Comment: So why add them twice? Normally you would ignore anything that attempts to add a duplicate to the collection, otherwise you could wind up with a situation where they could choose from 10 different apples. Screenshot?

Comment: @Skoder I'm not using Silverlight, but I was able to replicate the same problem in WPF. I solved it using a simple class `Fruit` with public property `Name` (and using a custom `ListBox.ItemTemplate`).

Comment: @HiTechMagic - I'm not allowed to show it, but the reason they can be added twice is that they can be removed individually (e.g. if the user decides to remove one apple). It has to be a listbox interface. The alternate could be to have a separate control next to the item with a number that can be adjusted, but that will need a redesign of the UI. That would have to be the last resort.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti - I tried it with a public getter/setter in my class, but it's the same issue. The custom ItemTemplate looks fine, and it displays the property, but it still considers it a duplicate.

Comment: Whoever tried to close this, can you post the duplicate thread?

Comment: @Skoder: it wasn't me that voted to close this as a duplicate, but the duplicate question mentioned was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836313/getting-the-index-of-multiple-selected-items-in-a-listbox-using-silverlight

Comment: @LukeWoodward - I came across that before posting but it's not a duplicate. The SelectedItems method is referring to unique items in the collection and doesn't work if you have duplicates in the ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a GUID property in my class and randomised it before adding to the ObservableCollection. User doesn't see the GUID, but the ListBoxItem is still considered unique and it now works. I'll leave this question open for a bit incase someone knows of a solution that doesn't require modifying the class unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

When you add two string with same value Listbox will treat them same. Better you create a custom class Like

class Composit { public string Key{get;set;} public string Value{get;set;} }

Bind the list with this class. This way if you set Apple to two object but key is different you will get correct result

Cheers! Vinod